# How to display the progress bar in Python 3.8, when i fill the dataframe parallelly?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

I wrote a python code to fill a dataframe row by row parallely, it works well. I am wondering, is it possible to show the progress bar when doing the parallel computing?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
   my_pool = Pool(10)  
   Data = pd.concat( my_pool.imap_unordered( parallelize_dataframe, range(0,len(dates)) ) )
   my_pool.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tqdm import tqdm

if __name__ == '__main__':
   my_pool = Pool(10)  
   Data = pd.DataFrame()
   for data in tqdm( my_pool.imap_unordered( parallelize_dataframe, range(0,len(dates)) ), total=len(dates)):
       Data = pd.concat([Data , data]).sort_index()
   my_pool.close()
```